# CMake avoid projects pollution in MSVC

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

I have a small C++ project which should be multi-platform and depends on some other libraries.

I'm using CMake and it's working fine after spending a lot of time configuring submodules and the CMake build scripts. The problem is: every time I generate a visual studio solution, I get the solution polluted by thousands of secondary projects from the libraries my project depends on. I tried to exclude unit tests and examples as much as I could by setting the CMake variables off, but there are still **a lot** of projects that I need to compile (and many other I don't even need to compile) in order for my dependencies to be correctly compiled before my small project.

How can I avoid this bloating and just keep my projects in the solution?

Comment: Can you change your submodules to external projects?

Comment: I might but I will not be able to `git --recursive` init them from their repositories

Comment: you'll need to be more specific. can you post an example?